# how to pass parameters to class method from javascript using asp.net script tags

Tags: javascript, asp.net, tags

I want to call one method of class from javascript,

In javascript I am doing something like this

```
<%=myMethod("abc")%>
```

but value "abc" is in variable for eg.

```
var myValue = "abc";
```

So how do I pass this variable?

I tried

```
<%= myMethod(myValue) %>
```

But it is not recognizing myValue variable

Comment: You're trying to pass a javascript variable to a server-side function?

Comment: yes I am trying to pass a javascript variable to a server-side function

Answer (score 0):

Define a function returning the variable value in code-behind, and render as:

```
<%= myMethod(MyValueGet()) %>
```

Comment: I dident understood. Please can you explain

Comment: I thought the variable was in code-behind (same notation). Passing a javascript variable is not possible that way because code behind function is executed before rendering the page, so the javascript variable is not yet set.

Comment: can you suggest any alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is executed on the user's computer (Client-side code). ASP.NET executes on the server (server-side code).

Passing a javascript varible to an ASP.NET function directly is not possible. To pass some state from the client to the server you must make a request (usually GET or POST) to the server including the javascript variable.

Some further reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

Answer (score 0):

To call a code-behind function passing a client variable, you could send a javascript ajax call, and define the server method as webservice method. This can help:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/calling-server-side-function-from-javascript-in-Asp-Net/

Answer (score 0):

I think the method your are trying to call should be made public and static. On top of that it should be decorated with the [WebMethod] attribute

In your page code-behind(.aspx.cs)

```
public class TestPage : Page
{
   [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
   [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
   public static string MyMethod(string para)
   {
      return "Yes this is working " + para;
   }
}
```

and in your page code (.aspx)

Add a script manager (from toolbox)

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server" />
```

and call the method

```
 <script>
     function Call(myValue){
       PageMethods.MyMethod(myValue);
     }
 </script>
```